# Как получить значение angular ui-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

В angular приложении раньше я использовал обычные input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="type" ng-model="flat.flatData.type_local" placeholder="Type" required>
```

Появилась необходимость вместо некоторых input использовать select. Для этого я установил angular ui-select и теперь вместо вышеуказанного input у меня ui-select:

```
<ui-select ng-model="flat.flatData.type_local"  on-select="someFunction(item, model)" theme="bootstrap">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Type">
      {{ $select.selected.type }}
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="t in flat.type_local | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind-html="t.type | highlight: $select.search"></div>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Мой controller выглядит следующим образом:

```
angular.module('flatCtrl', ['flatService', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select'])
    .controller('FlatController', function(Flat, socketio){
        vm = this;
        vm.type_local = {};

        vm.createFlat = function(){
            vm.message = '';
            Flat.create(vm.flatData)
                .success(function(data){

                    // clear up the form
                    vm.flatData = '';
                    vm.message = data.message;
                });
        };

        vm.type_local = [
            { type: 'One' },
            { type: 'Two' }
        ];
  vm.counter = 0;
  vm.someFunction = function (item, model){
  vm.counter++;
  vm.eventResult = {item: item, model: model};
  };
```

Проблема в том, что в случае с инпутами все работает, и их значение успешно записывается в базу данных MongoDB. В случае же с селектом, его значение в базу не записывается, хотя значения оставшихся инпутов по прежнему успешно записываются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удобно и положено использовать [ngOptions](http://angular-doc.herokuapp.com/api/ng.directive:select) для таких целей.

```
<select name="type"
        ng-model="type"
        ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in types">
    <option value="">Выберите</option>
</select>
```

`type.name` - это имя селекта, `type.id` - это значение (value) селекта, то есть то, что должно сохраняться в базу.

Можно также и вручную присваивать значение, как Вы делаете сейчас. Например:

```
ng-change="valueForSaveToDB = type.id"
```

Comment: Да, про это знаю, но хотел использовать именно ui-select, так как там много встроенных дополнительных опций, которые мне необходимы в будущем. Спасибо за ответ, тоже очень полезный!